# How to detect mouse x/y in keypress/keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change my cursor image to an animated **gif** when user press on key.

I tried to change the css "cursor" property but it doesn't move...

So I want to make a **div** with background image and place it in my cursor X/Y position.

What I tried to do so far is:

```
var xPlace;
var yPlace;

$(document).mousemove(function(eventParent) {
    xPlace = eventParent.pageX;
    yPlace = eventParent.pageY;
});

$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 109) {
        $("body").addClass("accessibility_cursordetect");
        var cursorDetect = '<div class="accessibility_cursordetect_img"></div>';
        $(cursorDetect).appendTo("body");
        $(".accessibility_cursordetect_img").css({
            "top": yPlace,
            "right": xPlace
        });
    }
});
```

The problem is - in my keydown function -xPlace&yPlace return "undefined"

How can I detect the x/y position of my cursor when the user press on a specific key ("m" for example = keyCode = 109)?

Thank you.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/zeun4tqu/   I do not get undefined in keydown, note though I did change `right` to `left` for css and added code to make it move with mouse. Can you show a working example of you getting undefined?

Comment: IT'S NOT WORKING FOR ME! add "alert" to the keydown code- it not alerting... :X

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the "cursor" property in the following manner to change the cursor image (using your profile photo in this example) on click of the button considering you already have the jQuery to add the body class:

```
.accessibility_cursordetect{
     cursor: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9b2dfec811b4643164cba1fd1f244404?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG), auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried this in the start - but cursor not allowed you to use animated gif - only static images...